# How to initialize and use an array of another class in a class? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am new to C++ and in Java, it was easy to use arrays of other classes and I was wondering if there was a way to use arrays of other classes like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Message
{...}
class UserMessageFile
{
    private:
        Message[] messages;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
        return 0;
}
```

Why can't I use an array of the Message class in my UserMessageFile class? Do I need to include the Message class inside of the UserMessageFile class before I can do this? How exactly do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot specify an array with unknown size as a class member (in fact you can't specify one unless it comes with a static initializer, and you can't have those in a class definition).

What you are looking for is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
class UserMessageFile
{
private:
    std::vector<Message> messages;
};
```

Comment: Okay I'll look into that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should almost always be looking to use `std::` types. So use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If you really need to use a c style array you must do this:

```
Messages messages[10]; // Your syntax must have the array 
                       // braces at the end and you must specify
                       // an array length.
```

[Here is a live example.](http://ideone.com/N1qER8)

Other syntax errors include:

1. Classes must end with a semicoln (`class a {};`).
2. Dont use `...` in your class, this isn't recognized.